# Macbook PRO vs Windows for .Net Core and .Net Framework Projects

Tags: windows, macbook

I searched on Google, Reddit but there is no good answers. If you are not .Net developer, you can pass the topic.

Let me know to you introduce the limits.

1. You are .Net developer
2. You have two computers, Macbook PRO for .Net Core projects and the other is Windows PC for .Net Framework projects.
3. You want to work into a single computer with-in above project dependencies.
4. You want to be mobile. Because you are traveling. Sometimes, you can plug-in your computer into external monitor and you are just working at any place.

What's your idea for computer with those limits.

I found a lot of solutions but I'm consider on performance, productivity, which one is the best? May be your ideas the better than my solutions.

Last year the company gave me Macbook Pro i5 (16 GB ram, storage ssd) for .Net Core projects. I love it. It's thin, It's so good if you are using .Net Core projects with Dockerize. I can work anywhere. But I bought Parallel Desktop software for .Net Framework projects. Mostly It's slow. It makes me noise and not helpful. I mean I can't work for .Net Framework projects. If you plug-in into external monitor It's getting worse. Also, If I open any project of .Net core in Parallels Desktop, I can't work .Net Core project on Macbook until terminate Parallels Desktop *(It's complicated)*. But I loved it to using MacBook.

So that's why, I always take Windows PC i7 (16 GB ram, storage ssd) with me for .Net Framework projects. It's good for .Net Framework projects but not good for Dockerize. WSL2 makes the computer freezes. So, I disabled WSL2, enabled Hyper-V. But when I'm running 3 container I can't work because of freezes. Also It's not mobility than Macbook, It's little bit heavy. It's helpful for .Net Core projects but Dockerize makes me stressful.

There are a lot of solutions.

1. Buy Macbook PRO M1 (with 16 GB Ram) and running Parallels Desktop for .Net Framework Projects.
2. Buy Macbook PRO i9 (with 32 GB Ram) and running Parallels Desktop for .Net Framework Projects.
3. Buy Windows Notebook (with 32 GB Ram) and forget Macbook.
4. Buy Windows PC (with 32 GB ram) for .Net Framework projects, put it at Home. Buy any Macbook PRO for .Net Core projects and connect to your Windows PC via RDP, Anydesk.
5. Buy any Macbook PRO for .Net Core projects and rent a Virtual Dedicated Server (16 GB) for .Net Framework projects.

That's my opinion but I'm not sure about performance, productivity. What is your suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I like option 3 most, but use one from a brand you or a popular reviewer trusts. The Lenovo Ideapad 3 with the Ryzen 7 5700U looks good, and it natively supports .NET Framework, .NET Core and .NET 5, although it only supports up to 16GB of RAM. (which is enough from my experience, I have an HP Probook with 16GB of RAM)